# Declaring class objects as fields in itself

Tags: c++, class

So I'm trying to create what is basically a linked list of rooms that stores pointers to the previous and next room in each room.

```
#ifndef Hospital_Room_h
#define Hospital_Room_h

class Room
{

public:

    Room( Room  const &);
    Room createRooms();

    Room next;
    Room prev;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Are you having any problems doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the editing toolbar, notice the button labeled `{}`. You can code-ify your program by selecting its text and clicking that button. I have done that for you for this program.

Comment: @David: Yeah, there's a problem doing this.  What's the size of a Room, if it must have two Rooms inside it?  By definition, you have `sizeof(Room) >= 2 * sizeof(Room)`, which is impossible.

Comment: Use an STL linked list then.

Answer (score 4):

To declare a pointer requires the `*` character, like so:

```
Room* next;
Room* prev;
```

To subsequently use the pointer requires either the `*` operator or the `->` operator, like so:

```
myFavoriteRoom = *(myRoom.next);

myFavoriteWindow = myRoom.next -> window;
```

If you are trying to use pointers, but do not yet understand how they work, I suggest you follow a [good book on C++ programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).